# Pattern matching: string not matching regex inside case object

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to iterate through a bunch of strings with enum-like case objects, each of them with their own regex. Doing it in a similar manner as below yields `scala.MatchError: somestring (of class java.lang.String)`. Any idea how to solve it?

```
case object X {val regex = "somestring".r}
case object Y {val regex = "de".r}

"somestring" match {
  case X.regex(_) => 1
  case Y.regex(_) => 2
```

Comment: There is neither `ma` nor `de` in `somestring`

Comment: You don't have any capture group so the parathesis should be empty: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/djjK6dDDRd6O5qRoP6xxEA/3

Comment: Amazing, that was it, such a stupid mislook. Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez!